# MongoDB crashes with out-of-memory or is being killed by oom-killer

Tags: mongodb, sharding, crash, mongodb-3.6, google-cloud-platform

A two shards MongoDB database regularly crashes with out-of-memory error or is being killed by the oom-killer. The system runs on **GCE Debian 9.4** with **MongoDB v3.6.5**, **WiredTiger** storage engine and without swap (as is the practice on GCE). The servers are n1-highmem-4 (**4 vCPUs**, **26 GB memory**). On the server runs just mongod and there are no other services. **mongos** are on different servers.

Usually process exit/crash happens once a day. If mongod process is killed by **oom-killer** this can be seen in the logs:

```
Jun 15 14:45:17 server4 kernel: [1731430.432189] Out of memory: Kill process 13130 (mongod) score 980 or sacrifice child
Jun 15 14:45:17 server4 kernel: [1731430.441717] Killed process 13130 (mongod) total-vm:28280536kB, anon-rss:26174876kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Sometimes mongod exits with leaving this in the mongod.log:

```
2018-06-15T02:14:32.456+0200 F -        [rsSync] out of memory.

 0x55cbc8535751 0x55cbc8534d84 0x55cbc8623b4b 0x55cbc86c665c 0x55cbc70fccff 0x55cbc70f8b02 0x55cbc707b3f1 0x55cbc86449b0 0x7fbbf3507494 0x7fbbf3249acf
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"2230751","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"222FD84","s":"_ZN5mongo29reportOutOfMemoryErrorAndExitEv"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"231EB4B"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"23C165C","s":"_Znam"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"DF7CFF","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail7OpQueueC1Ev"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"DF3B02","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail16oplogApplicationEPNS0_22ReplicationCoordinatorE"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"D763F1","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl10RSDataSync4_runEv"},{"b":"55CBC6305000","o":"233F9B0"},{"b":"7FBBF3500000","o":"7494"},{"b":"7FBBF3161000","o":"E8ACF","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.6.5", "gitVersion" : "a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.9.0-6-amd64", "version" : "#1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07)", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55CBC6305000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D4592BDFAA6C15459D2319DEAB7F10E9EB4E7D7" }, { "b" : "7FFC48D98000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A3207CC9FE1CAA3374AE7061AA5C3C5619B8A0E5" }, { "b" : "7FBBF4743000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "713D47D5F599289C0A91ADE8F0122B2B4AA78B2E" }, { "b" : "7FBBF42B0000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2CFE882A331D7857E9CE1B5DE3255E6DA76EF899" }, { "b" : "7FBBF4044000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2AA3B39763D943F56B3BD05C8E36E639BA95E12" }, { "b" : "7FBBF3E40000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B895F0831F623C5F23603401D4069F9F94C24761" }, { "b" : "7FBBF3C38000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D83E0642E645026DBB11F89F7DF7106BD821495" }, { "b" : "7FBBF3934000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1B95E3A8B8788B07E4F59EE69B1877F9DEB42033" }, { "b" : "7FBBF371D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "51AD5FD294CD6C813BED40717347A53434B80B7A" }, { "b" : "7FBBF3500000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4285CD3158DDE596765C747AE210AB6CBD258B22" }, { "b" : "7FBBF3161000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AA889E26A70F98FA8D230D088F7CC5BF43573163" }, { "b" : "7FBBF495A000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "263F909DBE11A66F7C6233E3FF0521148D9F8370" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55cbc8535751]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo29reportOutOfMemoryErrorAndExitEv+0x84) [0x55cbc8534d84]
 mongod(+0x231EB4B) [0x55cbc8623b4b]
 mongod(_Znam+0x21C) [0x55cbc86c665c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail7OpQueueC1Ev+0x7F) [0x55cbc70fccff]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail16oplogApplicationEPNS0_22ReplicationCoordinatorE+0x402) [0x55cbc70f8b02]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl10RSDataSync4_runEv+0x111) [0x55cbc707b3f1]
 mongod(+0x233F9B0) [0x55cbc86449b0]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x7494) [0x7fbbf3507494]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x3F) [0x7fbbf3249acf]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

We have tried to play with the cacheSizeGB parameter and reduced it to 10GB:

```
  cacheSizeGB: 10.0
```

But still the crash happens.

It is worth mentioning that there is a chunk moving process underway and that mongod instances that crash are the one from the shard that receive chunks.

What tuning options to use to avoid such crashes?

UPDATE: added small swap od 1GB, but still out-of-memory happens.

Comment: That missing swap file will fix the problem. Swap don't need to be big, but is should exists to avoid OOM situation with mongod. You can create that swap as file at the current filesystem, no need to have "own partition".

Comment: @JJussi tried with 1GB swap but didn't help. Still mongod exits with out-of-memory

Comment: Strange thing is that, that even mongod eventually uses all free memory, it should not use more than there is. However, OOM killer message says that mongod was using 26.97GB memory when process was killed. Could it be that mongod process see, somehow, more memory than what there is actually? (Because it is at virtual enviroment)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that we had a long running daily query and chunks that were moved were still retained in memory as were used by the cursor of the query. In this way with every chunk moved memory with chunk data was retained and at one moment all memory consumed.

As we removed this long-running query, there were no crashes.

Comment: It turns out that the query is not necessary ?